# Providing access to S3 without having an access key/secret?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use AWSSDK in .NET Core to interact with S3.

For this, I can specify an access key and secret.

However, I was under the impression that this isn't necessary, if the code trying to access S3 is running under an EC2 instance? Can this be done with some IAM magic instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2s can be associated with an `Instance Profile` which is sort of a container for an IAM role. See [Using Instance Profiles - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) for instructions on how to manage Instance Profiles.

Once an IAM role is attached to an EC2 (using an Instance Profile), applications running on the EC2 can assume that role.

Applications running on an EC2 follow a chain of credential providers to acquire credentials and Instance Profile credentials (provided via EC2 metadata service) is one of them. With most AWS SDKs you don't have to do anything special in your applications to use Instance Profile credentials. See your SDK docs for more details (e.g. [Java SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html)). With .NET Core, all you have to do is add something like this in your `Startup` class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
...
}
```

And then you can depend on `IAmazonS3` in your application classes and things would just work.